# How to popToRootViewController when you have a NavigationController within a NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

My **Storyboard** setup (that is related to this question) is the following.

```
LoginViewController -> NavigationController -> MainViewController ->
LeftMenuViewController -> NavigationController -> SettingsViewController
```

Basically I want to get from **SettingsViewController** to **LoginViewController** in one step.

So far I've tried the following:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And neither work. Is there anyway to do this with the way I have things setup? I understand the way I have things setup is probably not the best, but I'm using the `AMSlidingMenu` Library and it instructed me to have things setup this way.

Comment: So you are pushing `LeftMenuViewController` onto the first `NavigationController`?  And then how does it present the second `NavigationController`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the second NavigationController just presents normally. It doesn't seem like there is any difference.

Comment: When I say 'present' I mean, does it push a navigationcontroller onto the existing navigationcontroller (so you now have a navigation controller embedded in another one) or does it use `presentViewController` ?

Comment: It's all done in `StoryBoard` so I'm assuming there is a navigation controller embedded in the first.

Comment: So, in Storyboard have you selected LoginViewController then used "embed in navigation controller" so that the navigation controller is the left most thing you see on the storyboard, or is MainviewController embedded in the navigationcontroller?  Similarly for settings view controller - it is embedded in a second navigationcontroller?

Comment: No sir, The `LoginViewController` is the left most thing. `MainViewController` is the embedded one. And correct, `SettingsViewController` is embedded in another `NavigationController`.

Comment: In this situation, you might want to consider making the LoginViewController a modal so that it is presentable at any given time in your application. Login screens are commonly available in more than one area of an application, so making it a modal makes it easier to manage.

Comment: I would try and present via a modal `settingsViewController` segue, then when you are finished you can use an unwind segue to get rid of it and pop your `MainViewController` to root, alternatively push `settingsViewController` onto the existing navigation controller (but this seems less 'right' to me).  Having two navigation controllers embedded in one-another is going to cause grief.  Essentially there will be no direct link between `MainViewController` and `LeftViewController` in your storyboard

Comment: I agree with @Chris - Having the embedded `MainViewController` may make more sense, with `LoginViewController` presented modally when required - but it may depend on whether the user needs to log in every time they run the app or if it keeps a cookie/session and only need to login once/periodically

Comment: @Paulw11, this is a tough question to answer. Embedded Navigation Controllers is really not the ideal architecture unless the second Navigation Controller is the root of a modal with only a couple View Controllers at the most. Once you start manipulating Navigation Controllers programmatically, you are asking for extra work so I would suggest to make sure it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Chris I agree - I get the feeling that the second navigation controller is for a "settings" system, so navigation controller is probably right and, as you say, should be a modal presentation on top of the base view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped this problem for a while because I couldn't figure it out. But I just figured it out so I've come to answer my own question:

What I did was the following:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This allowed me to pop back to `LoginViewController`.